# ajax post datetime to moment js format

Tags: javascript, ajax, momentjs

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-12">
 <div class="box-body tableForum"></div>
</div>
```

Js

```
function getTicketData(ticketId) {

$.ajax({
    url: '/api',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        module: 'helpdesk/ticket-responses',
        method: 'get',
        params: [
            {
                'ticket.id': ticketId
            }
        ]
    },
    success: function (data) {
        var data = JSON.parse(data);
        var finalData = data['hydra:member'];

        var dataForum = '';
        // var postTime = moment().format("D MMM YYYY, kk.mm a"); //I tried this one and
        // $(".date-post").html(dataForum.toString()); //This one too

        $.each(finalData, function (index, value) {
            dataForum += '<div>';
            dataForum += '<div class="media-body"><span class="date-post pull-right"><i class="fa-clock-o"></i>  posted at '+value.createdAt+'</span>';
            dataForum += '</div>';

        });
        $('.tableForum').html(dataForum); 
        //console.log(finalData);
    }
});
}

function postTicketData(time) {
    var params;

        params = [
            {
                name: 'time',
                value: createdAt
            }
        ];
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: '/api',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            module: 'helpdesk/ticket-responses',
            method: 'post',
            params: params
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var data = JSON.parse(data);

            if(data == 401) {

            } else {

                    var ticketId =  ticket.split("/").pop();
                    getTicketData(ticketId)

            }
        }
    });
}
```

The default output format from DB is like this:

> posted at 2017-07-24T04:26:44+00:00

Basically I want the format like this:

> posted at 24-07-2017 16:26

or

> posted at 24 Jul 17 16:26

or

> posted at 24 Jul 17 04:26 pm

Can someone enlighten me, how to convert to the format I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the momentjs library, you have to understand the way to use it.
When you want to convert your date using moment just use

```
moment(data_from_db).format("D-MM-YYYY HH:mm")
```

The above example will produce 24-07-2017 16:26

If you want on different format you only need to change inside the format function. To know more about the format you can read on [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/)
website.

For your case, you only need to do something like below

```
$.each(finalData, function(index, value) {
    dataForum += '<div>';
    dataForum += '<div class="media-body"><span class="date-post pull-right"><i class="fa-clock-o"></i>  posted at '+moment(value.createdAt).format("D-MM-YYYY HH:mm")+'</span>';
    dataForum += '</div>';
});
```

Comment: Could it be like this? `moment('+value.createdAt+').format("D MMM YYYY, kk.mm a")`

Comment: you don't need to write `moment('+value.createdAt+')` because moment is a javascript library and it is not a string that's the reason you only need to write `moment(value.createdAt)` followed by format function. And your format also valid but it will return like 24 Jan 2017, 7.20 pm

Comment: Thank you Captain! you totally saved my day!